# Amending commit that is edited as part of a rebase in magit

Tags: git, emacs, magit

I'm using Emacs + it's in very many ways fabulous magit-mode to work with git. There is one aspect of my workflow though that I can't map to this, and thus this question.

Sometimes you have a commit which should be reworked into separate commits. I can interactively rebase my commits with magit, and declare my intend to edit said commit.

Now I have to switch over to git gui, select "ammend last commit" which shows me the staged changes, and unstage those parts I want to become a separate commit. Then I commit, stage the exclusions, and commit again - voila, I have a new commit within my history.

I have so far not found a way to accomplish this using Emacs. Any hints?

Comment: This is probably better asked on Emacs.SE.

Comment: Hey, how do you interactively rebase commits ? :)

Comment: @SeanAllred Oh, I wasn't aware there is one.Go to the log ("l l" from the magit-info buffer), go to a commit, and press "E". Will i-rebase all commits from there on. Make sure you save the buffer with "C-x #" as it's a remote buffer.

Comment: On the `next` branch rebasing has been improved a lot, e.g. the commits yet to be reapplied, as well as the already reapplied commits, are shown in the status buffer while a rebase is in progress. Your question ("how to split up a commit") I have answered in detail elsewhere: https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/966#issuecomment-60498587. (What Jordon suggests below is one way of doing it, but when using the `next` branch there is a more elegant variant).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After your begin the rebase, instead of going to the gui, do a magit-reset-head to HEAD~1, this will put you in the position to unstage the changes, and stage and commit as desired before finally Continuing the rebase from the magit status buffer.

---

Example scenario workflow:

1. commit changes to file A (commit 1)
2. commit changes to file B and file C (commit 2)
3. commit changes to file D (commit 3)
4. realize that you want the changes to file B and file C to be separate commits
5. run `magit-log`
6. begin an interactive rebase (<kbd>E</kbd>) at commit 2.
7. specify you want to edit (<kbd>e</kbd>) commit 2 and finish (<kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd>)
8. return to magit status buffer.
9. run `magit-reset-head` (<kbd>x</kbd>), specify `HEAD~1` in prompt.
10. you will see the changes for commit 2 staged.
11. unstage the changes to file C.
12. commit the staged changes for file B.
13. stage and commit the changes to file C.
14. continue and finish the rebase with <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>

You will now have four commits, each changing one file in the order A, B, C, D.